# Append results of a search of external .json

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to append results of a search of external .json

here i append the results of a search of an internal javascript array. (with a little help from lodash)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {  
        $('#dynam-now').click(function () {
         let searchString = $('#dynamId').val();

let result = _.filter(fruitChoices, function(object) {

return object.fruit.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) != -1;

});
        
        $('#ArrayD').html("");
 
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            $('#ArrayD').append(result[i].fruitname + " " + result[i].size + "  " + result[i].color + "<br>")
        };
    });
});   
   

var fruitChoices = [{
    "fruit": "apple",
    "fruitname" : "Apple",
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Red"
  },
     {
    "fruit": "banana",
    "fruitname" : "Banana",
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Yellow"
  },
  {
    "fruit": "orange",
    "fruitname" : "Orange",
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Orange"
  },
    {
    "fruit": "strawberry",
    "fruitname" : "Strawberry",
    "size": "Small",
    "color": "Red"
    }];
```

```css
#ArrayD {
            margin-top:25%;
                font-size: 18px;
         font-family: sans-serif;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Apple
    </title>
   

     <!-- Bootstrap CSS --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://aaronlilly.github.io/CDN/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<!-- Bootstrap JS --> 
<script src="https://aaronlilly.github.io/CDN/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Lodash --> 
<script src="https://aaronlilly.github.io/CDN/js/lodash.min.js"></script> 
    

   
</head>
<body>


    <br>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
           
           
            

                <input type="text" id="dynamId" size="37" placeholder="Search Field" style="margin-left: 50px;margin-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 5px;padding-top: 4px;">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                   
                    <button class="btn btn-info my-2 my-sm-0" caption="search" id="dynam-now"> Search</button>
                    
                </div>

                
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

                   <div id="ArrayD"> </div>
```

with my future external .json hosted here - https://aaronlilly.github.io/ApiExample/Apple4/apple4.json

but is written as -

```
{
   "results": 
  [
    {
    "fruit": "apple",
    "fruitname" : "Apple",
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Red"
  },
     {
    "fruit": "banana",
    "fruitname" : "Banana",
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Yellow"
  },
  {
    "fruit": "orange",
    "fruitname" : "Orange",
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Orange"
  },
    {
    "fruit": "strawberry",
    "fruitname" : "Strawberry",
    "size": "Small",
    "color": "Red"
    } 
  ]
  }
```

I would like to append the filtered search results. 
I have tried

```
  $(document).ready(function ()  
            {
                    $.ajax
                        ({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: " https://aaronlilly.github.io/ApiExample/Apple4/apple4.json"
                         }).done(function(data) 

                               {$(document).ready(function () {  
        $('#dynam-now').click(function () {
         let searchString = $('#dynamId').val();

let result = _.filter(data, function(object) {

return object.result.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) != -1;

});
        console.log(results.fruit)
        $('#ArrayD').html("");

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            $('#ArrayD').append(result[i].fruitname + " " + results.result[i].size + "  " + result[i].color + "<br>")
        };
    });
});   
                                console.log(data)


                              });
            });
```

and get errors such as - Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

i have tried to correct this, but not having much luck. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an issue with your `filter` function. It should be changed to:

```
let result = _.filter(data.results, function(object) {
    // object = { fruit: 'orange', fruitname: 'ora'...}
    return object.fruitname.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) !== -1;

});
```

Then `result` will be an array of matching fruits.

Comment: You have to change the next line from `console.log(results.fruit)` to `console.log(result[0].fruit)`